# Can anybody explain such behavior of accuracy and loss of my Net(caffe)?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, image-recognition

I used [this](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/) project for example(framework - caffe, arhitecture of net - mod of AlexNet, 400 images are used for training). I have this result:
[image]

or this:
[image]

Solver:

```
net: "./CDNet/Models/train.prototxt"
test_iter: 500
test_interval: 500
base_lr: 0.001
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 50
max_iter: 450000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "./CDNet/Models/Training/cdnet"
solver_mode: GPU
```

Model of net:
[image]

Can anybody explain such behavior of accuracy and loss of my Net? What I am doing wrong?

Author of tutorial has got this result: 
[image]